# Binary decomposition sequence

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, enumerator

I would like to process an ArrayList of items in a sequence which successively divides the list into halves. Something analagous to a binary search but not working on sorted data and using a breadth first rather than depth first order.

In this sequence, the first step would be to choose the item at position `n/2`. The second step would select the centre position of each half, this would result in selecting `n/4` and `3n/4`. The third step would divide these quarters in half again, selecting indices `n/8, 3n/8, 5n/8, 8n/8`. The indices `2n/8, 4n/8, 6n/8` would be skipped by this step since they were selected in steps one and two as `n/2` and `n/4, 3n/4`. The sequence would continue until every item was enumerated.

How could this be implemented C# 2.0 using IEnumerable?

Here is some code I wrote which generates a similar sequence but begins with index 0 and is not very elegant,

```
    private static IEnumerable BinaryDecomposition(ArrayList items)
    {
        ArrayList yieldedItems = new ArrayList();
        int n = 2;
        while (yieldedItems.Count < items.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i += (int)Math.Ceiling(1.0 * items.Count / n))
            {
                if (!yieldedItems.Contains(i))
                {
                    yieldedItems.Add(i);
                    yield return items[i];
                }
            }
            n *= 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I noticed in the examples you've given the "binary decomposition" sequence has less items than the original sequence: 8 => 7 and 16 => 12. Is this an expected behaviour? What's the rule behind it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The sequence should always generate exactly n items. I've updated the question to hopefully make things more clear.